'TonLib' object has no attribute '_tonlib_json_client_destroy'
I installed the "TonTools" library, I get this after calling await client.init_tonlib()
File "D:\PycharmProjects\Dev_dir\ref_bot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\ton\tonlibjson.py", line 136, in __del__
RuntimeError: Error in tonlibjson.__del__: 'TonLib' object has no attribute '_tonlib_json_client_destroy'

Full stack:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\PycharmProjects\Dev_dir\ref_bot\payments\ton_payment.py", line 28, in <module>
    asyncio.run(generate_address())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 654, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\PycharmProjects\Dev_dir\ref_bot\payments\ton_payment.py", line 10, in generate_address
    await client.init_tonlib()
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Dev_dir\ref_bot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\ton\client\tonlib_methods.py", line 67, in init_tonlib   
    wrapper = TonLib(self.loop, self.ls_index, cdll_path, self.verbosity_level, default_timeout=self.default_timeout)       
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Dev_dir\ref_bot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\ton\tonlibjson.py", line 92, in __init__
    tonlib = CDLL(cdll_path)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 376, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'D:\PycharmProjects\Dev_dir\ref_bot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\ton\distlib\windows\tonlibjson.amd64.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
Exception in tonlibjson.__del__: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Dev_dir\ref_bot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\ton\tonlibjson.py", line 133, in __del__
    self._tonlib_json_client_destroy(self._client)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'TonLib' object has no attribute '_tonlib_json_client_destroy'

Exception ignored in: <function TonLib.__del__ at 0x00000134F260ACA0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\Dev_dir\ref_bot\.venv\Lib\site-packages\ton\tonlibjson.py", line 136, in __del__
RuntimeError: Error in tonlibjson.__del__: 'TonLib' object has no attribute '_tonlib_json_client_destroy'

I have no idea why, I installed OpenSSL, it didn't help.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
